# Javascript Human Readable Filesize

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to convert this php function to javascript:

```
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
  $sz = 'BKMGTP';
  $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
  return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
}
```

Here's what I have so Far:

```
function human_filesiz(bytes){
            var decimals = 2;
            var sz = 'BKMGTP';
            var factor = Math.floor((bytes.length - 1) / 3);
            return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, factor));
            //return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
        }
```

Im Just struggling with the last line. Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: based on the new international standards KiB,MiB,GiB is 1024 and KB,MB,GB is 1000.. check out my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you have a look at: http://programanddesign.com/js/human-readable-file-size-in-javascript/ They have two version of a Javascript solution for Human Readable Filesize:

```
function fileSize(size) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024));
    return (size / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][i];
}
```

and

```
function readableFileSize(size) {
    var units = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    var i = 0;
    while(size >= 1024) {
        size /= 1024;
        ++i;
    }
    return size.toFixed(1) + ' ' + units[i];
}
```

Update loop criteria to `while(size >= 1024 && i < units.length - 1)` to prevent `undefined` after YB or last unit exceeded [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354746/712334) by [@holytrousers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615401/holytrousers).

Comment: I like the first comment on that link, nice two-liner solution.

Comment: if you want to respect the new standards the correct number to use in your case is 1000 and not 1024. and the k of KB should be lowercase in the second function.

Answer (score 8):

***Based on the new international standards:***

there are 2 ways now (SI & IEC)... or better 3 including the old one(JEDEC memory standards).

---

old standard (JEDEC & SI):

kB=1000, KB=1024

MB=1024=1000

GB=1024=1000

as you can see everything is messed up as you don't know if they are using 1024 or 1000 as multipler

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

---

thats why we have this 2 new standards now:

**Decimal (International System of Units [SI])**

kB,MB,GB..    = 1000

**Binary (International Electrotechnical Commission [IEC])**

KiB,MiB,GiB.. = 1024

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

here are 2 functions i just wrote using shorthand and bitwise to make it fast & short.

```
function fileSizeSI(a,b,c,d,e){
 return (b=Math,c=b.log,d=1000,e=c(a)/c(d)|0,a/b.pow(d,e)).toFixed(2)
 +' '+(e?'kMGTPEZY'[--e]+'B':'Bytes')
}
//kB,MB,GB,TB,PB,EB,ZB,YB

function fileSizeIEC(a,b,c,d,e){
 return (b=Math,c=b.log,d=1024,e=c(a)/c(d)|0,a/b.pow(d,e)).toFixed(2)
 +' '+(e?'KMGTPEZY'[--e]+'iB':'Bytes')
}
//KiB,MiB,GiB,TiB,PiB,EiB,ZiB,YiB
```

usage

```
fileSizeSI(5768374623);
//5.77 GB

fileSizeIEC(5768374623);
//5.37 GiB
```

**EDIT**

And here is a prototype for modern browsers that can handle both

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype,'fileSize',{value:function(a,b,c,d){
 return (a=a=='SI'?[1e3,'k','B']:[1024,'K','iB'],b=Math,c=b.log,
 d=c(this)/c(a[0])|0,this/b.pow(a[0],d)).toFixed(2)
 +' '+(d?(a[1]+'MGTPEZY')[--d]+a[2]:'Bytes');
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
// default(IEC) KiB,MiB,GiB,TiB,PiB,EiB,ZiB,YiB
// (SI) kB,MB,GB,TB,PB,EB,ZB,YB
```

usage

```
(1289139173).fileSize(); // default Binary IEC
//1.20 GiB

(1289139173).fileSize('SI'); // Metric SI
//1.29 GB
```

i always used 1024 to calculate the size ... so i put the new IEC standard as default.

if you have some questions about the functions just ask

Answer (score 1):

we should stop the loop when size exceeds what we have anticipated in the units array

```
function toHuman(size) {
    var units = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];  
    var i = 0;  
    var j = units.length - 1; 
    while(size >= 1024 && i<j) {  
        size /= 1024;  
        ++i;  
    }  
    return size.toFixed(1) + ' ' + units[i];  
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks like already accepted post, but with little improvement. I suggest you to edit accepted answer ( or leave a comment ) and delete this one

Comment: yes indeed and this is what i wanted to do but the website's design forces you to post a new answer ( you need 50 reputation points before you can make a comment.. nonsense )

Comment: but i can comment my post yeay !

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by osi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20459666/1697320) is great. If you want to understand what JS can do for your example though, you can take a look at this code which I made work for you:

```
function human_filesiz(bytes){
    var decimals = 2;
    var sz = 'BKMGTP';
    bytesStr = new String(bytes);
    var factor = Math.floor((bytesStr.length - 1) / 3);

    // rounding the number in JS:
    var number = bytes / Math.pow(1024, factor);
    var roundPrecision = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    number *= roundPrecision;
    var result = Math.round(number, decimals) / roundPrecision;
    result = result + sz.substring(factor, 1);
    return result;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrc2M/)

Answer (score 0):

I like [cocco's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461894/3637034).

I added rounding and locale conversion for the separators.

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'toFileSize', {
value: function(a, b, c, d){ return (a=a=='SI'?[1e3,'k','B']:[1024,'K','iB'],b=Math,c=b.log,d=c(this)/c(a[0])|0,+(b.round(this/b.pow(a[0],d)+"e+2")+"e-2")).toLocaleString()+' '+(d?(a[1]+'MGTPEZY')[--d]+a[2]:'Bytes');},
writable: false,
enumerable: false
});
```